# findAll method in BeautifulSoup does not work in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

in this code, i have a problem. When i print the links, it returns empty list. so code does not correct. what is the problem and how can fix it?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

search = input('Serach for:')
params = {"q": search}
r = requests.get('http://www.bing.com/search', params=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find("ol", {"id": "b_results"})
links = results.findAll("li", {"class": "b_algo"})

for item in links:
    item_text = item.find("a").text
    item_href = item.find("a").attrs["href"]

    if item_href and item_href:
        print(item_text)
        print(item_href)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the URL to search to the following content, I think the search results will return.

```
r = requests.get('https://www.bing.com/?setmkt=en-us&setlang=en-us&', params=params)
```

Comment: I just changed it to the initial URL of the bing site.

Comment: Thanks! Can you get a link for google? When I use https://www.google.com/search, I did not get anything. and sometimes it gives me an error. this error is: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'

Comment: When I used this link of google, I get this error. Can you help me, what is the problem? the error:     links = results.findAll("li", {"class": "b_algo"})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'

Comment: Use Chrome's Developer Tools to find out the class name, etc. (win:CTRL+SHFT+F12)

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code, it gives me a prompt "search for:"

If I type 'dog' and then hit enter, I get a list back

```
dogの意味・使い方・読み方 | Weblio英和辞書
https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/dog
dogの意味 - 英和辞典 - コトバンク
https://kotobank.jp/ejword/dog
dogの意味 - goo辞書 英和和英
https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/dog/
dog - ウィクショナリー日本語版 - Wiktionary
https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/dog
【楽天市場】犬服のiDog アウトレット（プチプラドッ …
https://item.rakuten.co.jp/idog/c/0000000129/
with DOG｜仙台のトリミングサロン・ペットホテル・ …
https://withdog-sendai.jp/
D･O･G WEBSTORE-犬服SHOP-
http://d-o-gweb.com/
DOG inTheパラレルワールドオーケストラ OFFICIAL SITE
http://inu-para.com/
【楽天市場】ドッグフードカタログ｜愛犬にあったフー …
https://event.rakuten.co.jp/pet/food/dog/
ドック - Wikipedia
https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%89%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF
```

This would indicate that your program is working. Are you typing in something to search for when you run this via command line?

Comment: it is interesting. because i get nothing, when I write anything like dog or something else!
Maybie  It may not be installed properly. Because I didn't have that method findAll.